# Найти слова а потом их отсортировать

Tags: java

Есть задание, где сначала надо вычислить слова с длинной слова больше среднего значения, a потом отсортировать их так, чтобы сначала шли слова с числами.

Сделал что-то типа этого. Как упростить и выполнить сортировку? Как сначала вывести слова с цифрами, а потом просто слова?

вот мой пример:

```
public List<String> convertText(String text) {
    String[] words = text.split("\\p{P}?[ \\t\\n\\r]+"); // split by whitespace

    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0;

    for (String word : words) {
        double wordLength = word.length();
        sum += wordLength;
        count++;
    }

    final double average = sum / count;

    List<String> list = Arrays.stream(words).filter(s -> s.length()>= average).collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (!list.get(i).matches(".*\\d+.*")){
            list.add(list.size() - 1, list.remove(i));
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Я как-то не понял. Вся ваша сортировка : длинна слова - длинна слова "intelligent". При чем тут вообще "intelligent"? И если это вся сортировка, что вам нужна, то не знаю как можно сделать проще...

Comment: @Виктор ну я и спрашиваю как ее реализовать! чтобы было по длине слова но сначала шли слова с цифрами! Обновил текущее решение

Comment: Напишите компаратор, который сравнивает два слова по вашему правилу: ` чтобы было по длине слова но сначала шли слова с цифрами!`

Answer (score 0):

Я о Java, конечно, мало чего знаю, но рабочее решение показать могу. Написал я простой код, в котором есть temporary массивы, - это проще для понимания.

```java
public List<String> convertText(String text) {
    String[] words = text.split("\\p{P}?[ \\t\\n\\r]+");
    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0;

    for (String word : words) {
        double wordLength = word.length();
        sum += wordLength;
        count++;
    }

    final double average = sum / count;

    List<String> list = Arrays.stream(words).filter(s -> s.length()>= average).collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Create a list with words containing digits
    final List<String> wordsContainingDigits = list.stream()
        .filter(w -> w.matches(".*\\d+.*"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Remove all the words that contain
    // digits from the initial list
    IntStream.range(0, wordsContainingDigits.size() - 1)
        .forEach(idx -> list.remove(idx));

    // Create the instance of a new list, which would
    // in future would be sorted.
    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Fill the new array with the words containing digits first,
    // and then with the other.
    Stream.of(wordsContainingDigits, list).forEach(newList::addAll);

    return newList;
}
```

Comment: И да, конечно, для того, чтобы это всё получилось производительнее, нужно написать компаратор, который говорил, что строка "больше", если она содержит цифры. При этом, сортировать нужно в порядке убывания.

Answer (score 0):

Пишите свой компаратор.

- Если оба слова содержат числа, то сравниваете по ним
- Если только одно слово содержит число, то компаратор возвращает >0
- Если оба слова без чисел, то сравниваете их как строки

При этом учтите, что если сравнивать числа как строки, то результат будет не правильны. Хотя вы не указали какой результат вам нужен